# Validate propTypes on parent and child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Should I be adding propTypes to parent components and their child components?

For example I have a `<Header modal={this.state.modal} lives={this.state.lives} score={this.state.score} />` component that is passed 3 props and I validate like so:

```
const Header = function(props) {
  if (props.modal) {
    return (<Logo logo={logo} />);
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Lives lives={props.lives} />
        <Score score={props.score} />
      </div>
      );
  }
};
Header.propTypes = {
  modal: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  lives: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  score: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
```

As you can see there are two child components `<Lives lives={props.lives} />` and `<Score score={props.score} />`.  I've added propTypes to those components as well.

```
const Score = function(props) {
  return (
    <p className="score score--right">
      {props.score} pts
    </p>
    );
};
Score.propTypes = {
  score: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
```

So is it redundant to be checking the same props twice?  And is this just overcomplicating things (making my code more difficult to manage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should validate `propTypes` in every components regardless of whether it has been validated in the parent component. Think like: If a component uses a prop, you should validate the type of the prop

One of the major advantage of React is component **re-usability**. Even in you case, the `Score` may be only used by `Header` at the moment, you may later on find it useful in other places and `Score` is getting `score` from other sources, you should make sure it receives the correct type.

If you are worried the bundled size from these duplication of proptype validations in production, there is a [**bable plugin**](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types) to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

The PropTypes kind of defines the properties and types that your component expects. Defining it in the parent and child component isn't really redundant, because the idea is that the Score component is a presentation component that **can be reused somewhere else if necessary**.

Thus, it's really a good practice to make sure that  your Score component is receiving the expected properties. It also makes you aware of the 'dependencies' that your component has to external data.